# R dplyr basic percentage

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize, mutated

I just can't seem to figure out this basic percentage by totals

Here is my simple `data.frame`

```
A=data.frame(sex=c('f', 'f', 'm')) 

library(dplyr) 
A%>%
    mutate(sex_totals=count(sex=='f')/count(a) # ????
```

Basically a new column should say

```
sex    sex_totals
f.      33.33
f.       33.33
m.     33.33
```

Comment: If there are two 'f', shouldn't that be 0.667

Answer (score 2):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
A %>% 
   add_count(sex) %>% 
   mutate(sex_total = n/n())
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question.

this

```
A %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise(sex_totals = n()) %>%
  mutate(sex_percent = sex_totals / sum(sex_totals) * 100) %>%
  select(sex, sex_percent)
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  sex   sex_percent
  <fct>       <dbl>
1 f            66.7
2 m            33.3
```